# responsive css calendar format breaks when not full width of page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have mocked up a responsive calendar.  This calendar is used to display the shifts for a local fire department.
[See this JS fiddle for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/krisis/7by1kLo2/)
As you can see the calendar re-sizes but keeps the same aspect ratio of its "cells" as you change the frame size of the fiddle.

The solution I have above works as long as it is placed inside a full width container in the html page.

### THE PROBLEM

As soon as I place the calendar inside a html div that is not the full width of the page the calendar does not display correctly. The cells are not square and the overlayed items (x, O, and square) are not positioned correctly. 
This is because I base the height of each cell on the **viewport** width or **vw**.  see the css "**.pCal ul li**" and the property **height:14vw;**

[See this fiddle for an example of the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/krisis/vtwj4v2o/)

The following image captures the problem (you can see the column on the left and right and the incorrect calendar displayed in the middle)
[image]

### QUESTION:

can someone help me correct my css so that the calendar displays properly even when inside a html element that is not the full width of the page.
*I would really prefer to have a css only solution but am open to javascript if needed.*

### ADDITIONAL INFO

for completeness i need to add the following details.  this solution uses the [FOUNDATION 5.5](http://foundation.zurb.com/frameworks-docs.html) front end framework.

HERE IS MY HTML(if fiddle does not show):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns" style="background:lightGrey;height:150px;">Left Column</div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-2 columns calPrev">&lt;</div>
            <div class="small-8 columns calMonth">March 2015</div>
            <div class="small-2 columns calNext">&gt;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row calRow">
            <div class="small-12 columns pCal">
                <ul class="small-block-grid-7">
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>SUN</span>

                    </li>
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>MON</span>

                    </li>
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>TEU</span>

                    </li>
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>WED</span>

                    </li>
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>THU</span>

                    </li>
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>FRI</span>

                    </li>
                    <li class="calHead">
                        <span>SAT</span>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-29.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-30.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-1.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-2.svg">
                        </div>
                        <dl class="calDayOverlay">
                            <dt class="calLayer2 calX">
                                <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-special-X.svg">
                            </dt>
                            <dt class="calLayer3 calCircle">
                                <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-special-O.svg">
                            </dt>
                            <dt class="calLayer4 calSquare">
                                <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-special-SQR.svg">
                            </dt>
                        </dl>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-3.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-4.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-5.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-6.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-7.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift3" />
                            <dt class="shiftWh shift3" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift3" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-8.svg">
                        </div>
                        <dl class="calDayOverlay">
                            <dt class="calLayer2 calX">
                                <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-special-X.svg">
                            </dt>
                        </dl>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-9.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-10.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-11.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-12.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-13.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img class="calToday" src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-14.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-15.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-16.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-17.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-18.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-19.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-20.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-21.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-22.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-23.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-24.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-25.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-26.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-27.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-28.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-29.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftOr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-30.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-31.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftBl shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-1.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <dl class="calDayParts">
                            <dt class="shiftRd shift2" />
                            <dt class="shiftGr shift2" />
                        </dl>
                        <div class="calDay">
                            <img src="http://www.krisis.ca/Portals/0/development/effu/cal-day-2.svg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns" style="background:lightGrey;height:150px;">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

HERE IS MY CSS: (you will need to include a reference to foundation 5 css - you can use [this CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.css))

```
.calRow {
    max-width:100%;
}
.calMonth, .calPrev, .calNext {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:gray;
    font-size:2em;
    margin:15px 0;
}
.calMonth {
    text-align:center;
}
.calPrev {
    text-align:left;
}
.calNext {
    text-align:right;
}
.pCal ul li {
    text-align:center;
    height:14vw;
    padding:0;
    border-left:solid 1px gray;
    border-top:solid 1px gray;
}
.pCal ul li:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
}
.pCal ul li dl {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
}

.pCal ul li dl dt {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.pCal ul li.calHead {
    font-size:1.2em;
    border:none;
    color:gray;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.calToday {
    border-bottom:0.5em solid lightGrey;
}

.calDay {
    position:relative;
    padding:15%;
    margin:0;
    top:-100%;
}

.calLayer2, .calLayer3, .calLayer4 {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
}
.calLayer2 {
    top:-200%;
}
.calLayer3 {
    top:-300%;
}
.calLayer4 {
    top:-400%;
}

/*  SHIFT HEIGHT / SIZE STYLES  */

.shift2 {
    height:50%
}
.shift3 {
    height:33.33%
}
.shift4 {
    height:25%
}


/* OVERLAY STYLES  */
.calX img{
    width:100%;
    padding-top:2%;
}
.calCircle img{
    width:100%;
    padding:9% 7%;
}
.calSquare img {
    width:100%;
    padding:7%;
}

/*  SHIFT COLOR STYLES  */

.shiftYw {
    background:yellow;
}
.shiftOr {
    background:orange
}
.shiftBl {
    background:blue
}
.shiftRd {
    background:red
}
.shiftGr {
    background:green
}
.shiftWt {
    background:white
}
.shiftBk {
    background:lightGray
}
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Here you go. You might want to clean up a bit

https://jsfiddle.net/vtwj4v2o/9/

Comment: Super fast and its perfect.  please post the changes you made to the css as an answer so I can accept it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the basic changes is to skip the height of the li element, and use a percentage padding instead. By doing so, the boxes will stay square. The rest is just some absolute positioning of the inner elements.